# compare columns of one data frame to other based on common column(unique)-R

Tags: r

I have a data frame , where I am trying to compare columns of one data frame to other  based on common column(unique)

first data frame

```
id<-c(1,2,3,4)
unique<-c("GIAGON2531","FedGon1083","AntGon1083","ShaBac3068")
df1<-data.frame(id,unique)
```

Second data frame  df2

```
unique<-c("BraRob5259","FedGon1083","AHMABD0646","ShaBac3068")
df2<-data.frame(unique)
```

Expected result:

[image]

and not equal:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can use `inner_join`

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(df1, df2)
```

If we need the rows that are not the same, use `anti_join`

```
anti_join(df1, df2)
```

Comment: this inner join is giving the rows which are present in both the dataframe. can you guide me how to get the rows which are not same

Comment: @priya updated the post.